# "Twisted" bimodule structure and left module structure.

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, let $\Lambda$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-algebra with finite global dimension. All modules are finitely generated left modules unless stated otherwise. The composition $fg$ of morphisms
(or arrows) means that $f$ is first and $g$ is next. For each $K$-algebra endomorphism $\phi$ of $\Lambda$, we denote by $\Lambda_{\phi}$ the $\Lambda\otimes_K \Lambda^{\text{op}}$-module such that the right action is given by $a\cdot b := a\phi(b)$.

> **Lemma 4.1**. For a $\Lambda \otimes \Lambda^{\text{op}}$-module $X$, the following conditions are equivalent.
>
> (a) $X \simeq \Lambda$ as $\Lambda$-modules.
>
> (b) $X \simeq \Lambda_{\phi}$ as $\Lambda \otimes \Lambda^{\text {op}}$-modules for some $K$-algebra endomorphism $\phi$ of $\Lambda$.
>
> **Proof**. (b) $\implies$ (a) This is clear.
>
> (a) $\implies$ (b). Fix an isomorphism $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\Lambda}(X, \Lambda)$. For each $\lambda \in \Lambda$, the right multiplication $(\cdot \lambda) \in \operatorname{End}_{\Lambda}(X)$ gives an endomorphism $f^{-1} \cdot(\cdot \lambda) \cdot f \in \operatorname{End}_{\Lambda}(\Lambda)$. This is given by the right multiplication of an element $\phi(\lambda) \in \Lambda$. Then $\phi$ gives the desired $K$-algebra endomorphism of $\Lambda$.

I don't know how to show (b) $\implies$ (a), could you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Just forget the right module structure (in other words, the $\Lambda^{\mathrm{op}}$-module structure).

Comment: @Roland Then $X$ is a general left $\Lambda$-module, why is it isomorphic to $\Lambda$ itself?

Comment: You know that $X\simeq \Lambda_\phi$ as $\Lambda\otimes\Lambda^{\mathrm{op}}$-module, but $\Lambda_\phi$ is just $\Lambda$ as a left module (with an extra right module structure). It follows that $X\simeq\Lambda$ just by forgetting the right module structure.

Comment: @Roland Excuse me, according to the definition, isn't $\Lambda_{\phi}$ a general $\Lambda$-module as a left module? Why is it just $\Lambda$ as a left module?

Comment: No, $\Lambda_\phi$ is the module such that its underlying set is $\Lambda$, its left module structure is the standard one (by left multiplication) and its right module structure is the twisted one you described.

Comment: @Roland Thank you!

Comment: @Puvas where is this lemma taken from?

Comment: @FM It is taken from "n-REPRESENTATION-FINITE ALGEBRAS AND TWISTED FRACTIONALLY CALABI-YAU ALGEBRAS, MARTIN HERSCHEND AND OSAMU IYAMA"

Comment: @Puvas Thanks! (some extra characters so I can send this comment...)